# How many pairs of $(x, y)$ satisfied this equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help to solve in $\mathbb{Z}$ the following equation
$$yx^{2}+xy^{2}=30$$ I tried to solve it by factor $30$ to $5\times 6$ and I get those two pairs  $(2, 3) \& (3, 2) $...  is their any other pairs of  $(x, y) $? ..

Answer (score 6):

Factor it as $xy(x+y)=30$. Write $30=2\times3\times5$. Therefore $y$ has to be a factor of $30$.

So $y=\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm5,\pm6,\pm10,\pm15,\pm30$.

However, if $y\geq6$ and $x\geq1$ then $xy(x+y)\geq42$. If $y\geq6$ and $x\leq-1$ then we must also have $x\leq-7$ since otherwise one factor is negative and two are positive. Then also $xy(x+y)\geq42$.

- $y=1$ gives $x(x+1)=30$, this gives $x=5 \vee x=-6$.
- $y=2$ gives $2x(x+2)=30$, this gives $x(x+2)=15$, thus $x=3$ or $x=-5$.
- $y=3$ gives $3x(x+3)=30$, this gives $x(x+3)=10$, thus $x=2$ or $x=-5$.
- $y=5$ gives $5x(x+5)=30$, this gives $x(x+5)=6$, thus $x=1$ or $x=-6$.
- $y=-1$ gives $-x(x-1)=30$, this gives $x(x-1)=-30$, which has no solutions.
- $y=-2$ gives $-2x(x-2)=30$, this gives $x(x-2)=-15$, which has no solutions.
- $y=-3$ gives $-3x(x-3)=30$, this gives $x(x-3)=-10$, which has no solutions.
- $y=-5$ gives $-5x(x-5)=30$, this gives $x(x-5)=-6$, thus $x=2$ or $x=3$.
- $y=-6$ gives $-6x(x-6)=30$, this gives $x(x-6)=-5$, thus $x=1$ or $x=5$.
- $y=-10$ gives $-10x(x-10)=30$, this gives $x(x-10)=-3$, which has no real solutions.
- $y=-15$ gives $-15x(x-15)=30$, which has no real solutions.
- $y=-30$ gives $-30x(x-30)=30$,  which has no real solutions.

**Conclusion:** We get the pairs $(5,1), (1,5), (-6,1), (1,-6), (2,3), (3,2), \\ (2,-5), (-5,2), (5,-6), (-6,5), (3,-5), (-5,3)$

Comment: It will factor to $ 15 \times 2$

Comment: 15 is not a prime factor.

Comment: But sir how many pairs of $(x, y) $ that satisfied this equation?

Comment: Let me explain something about the use of the site. The site is designed to make you learn as much as possible. Therefore you should tell us what you have tried. Otherwise the question will attract downvotes, and you won't get complete answers. If you add what you already know about the problem, by editing the question, I will give a more appropriate hint.

Comment: it hasn't a prime factors.. it was a result of $(1\times 30) ( 2\times 15 ) (3\times 10 )( 5\times 6)$ only

Comment: ... and $2 \times 3 \times 5$. By the way, if you use the & command in LaTeX, you need to use \&.

Comment: I edited the question sir...  NOW.. is their any other pairs of  $(x, y) $

Comment: There are a LOT more pairs. Don't forget you can mark the most helpful answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks professor for Your help..  But final question..  why  $y <6$?

Comment: @user257567 I explained that in the third sequence.

Comment: another thanking for You sir